Amazon delivery driver has PSA for customers who leave delivery instructions
What is PSA in "‘Yall got me messed up’: Amazon delivery driver has PSA for customers who leave delivery instructions".
I don't think it stands for Psoriatic arthritis, (PsA), a chronic, autoimmune form of arthritis that causes joint inflammation and occurs with the skin condition psoriasis. Or is it? Thank you!

PSA = Public Service Announcement - Literally a PSA is an advert, often on TV or radio, from the government that gives information or a warning (For example "Only you can prevent wildfires" or "Follow the Green Cross Code")
It's Not being used literally here. Here it just means "an unrequited sharing of information".

I use it similarly tongue-in-cheek myself often, when offering unsolicited advice to a large audience.
